# Automatically renaming duplicate files in folder with incremental numbers

Tags: windows, file, memory-management, duplicates, explorer

I have a function which automatically maps new files into a windows folder. Once run, the program will output a file named "Test001" into the folder. However, there are times where the program will need to run twice but it will populate a duplicate file instead, ie "Test001 (1)".

Is there a method to rename the duplicate file automatically. Rather than "Test001 (1)", I want the file to be renamed to "Test002" instead.

I tried searching for ideas online and some suggested using Window Powershell. However, I am unable to find a solution that truly fits my desired outcome.

Rather than changing it on my system side (which could be costly and not viable), I was wondering if I could change the folder properties or system settings instead.

I hope there can be some valuable insights to be found.